# How to make an 1,0 mapping file between the unique values of two columns in Excel?

Tags: excel

Hi I have a table like the following:

```
Ortho   Path
L20795  ABbiosynthesis
L43787  ABbiosynthesis
L43789  ABbiosynthesis
L20795  CDbiosynthesis
L43787  CDbiosynthesis
L20632  CDbiosynthesis
L43789  CDbiosynthesis
L20074  XYZpentaABC
L20232  XYZpentaABC
L20508  XYZpentaABC
L20626  XYZpentaABC
L20632  XYZpentaABC
L21692  XYZpentaABC
L21715  XYZpentaABC
L21782  XYZpentaABC
L21825  XYZpentaABC
L25605  XYZpentaABC
L27823  XYZpentaABC
L43767  XYZpentaABC
L45016  XYZpentaABC
L43821  ABCDEFbiosynthesis
L20632  ABCDEFbiosynthesis
L20019  MNOPbiosynthesis
L20059  MNOPbiosynthesis
L20065  MNOPbiosynthesis
L20208  MNOPbiosynthesis
L20209  MNOPbiosynthesis
L20647  MNOPbiosynthesis
L21716  MNOPbiosynthesis
L22371  MNOPbiosynthesis
L22372  MNOPbiosynthesis
L27535  MNOPbiosynthesis
L41610  MNOPbiosynthesis
L46363  MNOPbiosynthesis
L48474  MNOPbiosynthesis
```

I want to make a 0,1 mapping between the unique elements of the first and the second column of the table. The unique values from the second column will be the column names in the output file and the unique names in the first column will be the row names. If a unique value in the first column  (e.g. L48474 and MNOPbiosynthesis) is associated with one of the unique values from the second column then their corresponding value will be 1, if there is no association (L20232    and MNOPbiosynthesis), their corresponding value will be 0. I am expecting an output like the following:

```
    ABbiosynthesis  CDbiosynthesis  XYZpentaABC ABCDEFbiosynthesis  MNOPbiosynthesis
L20795  1   1   0   0   1
L43787  1   1   0   0   0
L43789  1   1   0   1   0
L20795  1   1   0   0   0
L43787  1   1   0   0   1
L20632  0   1   1   1   0
L43789  1   1   0   0   0
L20074  0   0   1   0   0
L20232  0   0   1   0   1
```

Can anyone please tell me how to do that?

Thanks a lot

Comment: You could try match().

Comment: Thanks solar. Can you please little elaborate?

Comment: Have you looked at the help entry for match()? have you checked on here for similar questions? what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @SolarMike, use `MATCH` function:

```
=IFERROR((MATCH($D2 & "-" & E$1,$A:$A & "-" & $B:$B,0))^0,0)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks  basic for the reply.don't know why it is not working in my case!!!

Comment: @CHANDA7 What exactly doesn't work? Error? Wrong result?